# How to disable "Save entity connection settings in app.config" always

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, application-settings, ef-model-first

When i execute the command "Generate Database from Model..." from my EntityFramework-Model (.edmx) the CheckBox "Save entity connection settings in app.config" is always checked.

But i want that it is **not** checked by default. Is there a way in the Registry or somewhere else to specify the default value of this checkbox.

I´m working on a class library project and i don´t need the app.config there. Also i want that i´m ask each time which database connection should be used, when i execute the command named above. Cause i´m working with diffrent build configurations and each build configuration has it´s own database to use.